# Insufficient power for RPI + 7" Touch Screen

Tags: power-supply, touchscreen, usb-power, voltage, current

I have a raspberry pi 3B. It is connected to a 7" RPI Touch screen, (made by RPI). The screen gets 5v from the pi and the pi is connected to a 5v, 2.1A USB power pack.

For some reason the power pack isn't supplying enough power. After 20 seconds of booting, the screen turns white, and it resets.

I dont understand why the battery pack isn't supplying enough power. I connected the same thing to a 2.1A 5V usb wall adapter and I had no issues.

**Im not sure exactly what I should measure, but here is the data I have gathered so far:**

- Power adapter voltage: 5.18v
- Power pack voltage: 5.10v

Comment: what's your question about Raspberry Pi then?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: you did not ask a question ... furthermore, you said that the Raspberry Pi operates normally when powered by a USB wall adapter, and the RPi fails to operate when powered by a battery pack ... so, what is your question that is actually about the Raspberry Pi? ... what problem, related to RPi, do you perceive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your battery pack does not supply enough power. The recommended minimum is 2.5A for the Pi, the fact that it even runs is luck. I have seen from 2A to 3A recommended. My best recommendation is get a power pack that will supply at least 3.5A (2.5A minimum should work) and a wall wart that will do the same, that way you should be ok for the near future depending on what you connect.